# Rails paperclip multiple attachment - Getting attached files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, paperclip, attachment

I've achieved to upload multiple images using paperclip.
And are stored to a private path:

```
:path => ":rails_root/data/images/:id/:basename.:extension"
```

Now I would like send them with a restful service, having as a parameter the component id.
The problem is that I don't know how to get their images, because the components don't store in database the images, I've write

```
has_many :assets
```

but the migraton created some days ago didn't had the assets.

Comment: Have you added `add_attachment :assets, :image` to migration while creating assets model?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new at rails and I don't know exactly what to do.
Now I have a model compoment that has_many assets, and this assets has_attached_file image.
So, what should I do exactly? What migration should I call?

Comment: have you created assets models using `rails g model`?

Comment: Yes, with a reference to component.
The problem is that the component doesn't know about de assets I think, because when I get a component json information, doesn't appear anything about the images, so I don't know how to achieve them.

Comment: you should generate another migration `rails g migration AddImagesToAssets` and put 
`
class AddImagesToAssets < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_attachment :assets, :image
  end

  def self.down
    remove_attachment :assets, :image
  end
end
`

Comment: `rake aborted!`
`An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:`

`undefined method 'add_attachment'`
That's what I'm getting.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a migration which creates assets table with paperclip fields:

```
create_table :assets do |t|
  t.timestamps
end
add_attachment :assets, :image
```

Comment: I've tryied `rails g migration AddAssetToComponent` but the file created, has no add_attachments. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try to use paperclip migration generator: `rails generate paperclip asset image` [Paperclip Quick Start](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Quick-Start)

Comment: I did it! I thing that the problem is that component don't know about asset, not the asset about de image.

Comment: You should change image definition to something like this `:path => ":rails_root/public/data/images/:id/:basename.:extension", :url => '/data/images/:id/:basename.:extension'` and then use `asset.image.url` to get the url.

Comment: To make file available using http you should put it to the public directory. So, you shouldn't use /data directory. So, you should change image definition to `:path => ":rails_root/public/data/images/:id/:basename.:extension", :url => '/public/images/:id/:basename.:extension'` (there was a mistake in previous comment)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
rails g paperclip Asset image
```

Comment: I did it. The images are stored correctly, but what I said is that the component don't know which assets have.

Comment: Sorry, I think that maybe the problem is on the route. When I'm trying to show them I get the following error:
`Started GET "/Users/.../data/images/8/image_2.jpg"`
`ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/Users/.../data/images/8/image_2.jpg"):`

Comment: Ok! I haven't find the way to show it, but it works sending it by restful action:
`send_file @component.assets.first.image.path, :type => @component.assets.first.image_content_type` So it is ok!